# weird behavior with 3d histogram in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, data-visualization

I have an Nx3 matrix in scipy/numpy and I'd like to make a 3 dimensional bar graph out of it, where the X and Y axes are determined by the values of first and second columns of the matrix, the height of each bar is the third column in the matrix, and the number of bars is determined by N.

Furthermore, I want to plot several groups of these matrices, each in a different color (a "grouped" 3D bar plot.)

When I try to plot it as follows:

```
ax.bar(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], zs=data[:, 2],
               zdir='z', alpha=0.8, color=curr_color)
```

I get really weird bars -- as seen here: http://tinypic.com/r/anknzk/7

Any idea why the bars are so crooked and weirdly shaped? I just want one bar at the X-Y point, whose height is equal to the Z point.

Comment: Looking at the docs, consider using the `bar3d` method: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the keyword argument `zs` correctly.  It refers to the planes at which each set of bars is placed (defined along the axis `zdir`).  They are crooked because it makes the assumption that a set of bars defined by a `ax.bar` call are in the same plane.  You are probably better off calling `ax.bar` multiple times (one for each plane).  Follow [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#bar-plots) closely.  You will want `zdir` to be either `'x'` or `'y'`.

**Edit**

Here is the full code (based heavily on the example linked above).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# this is just some setup to get the data
r = numpy.arange(5)
x1,y1 = numpy.meshgrid(r,r)
z1 = numpy.random.random(x1.shape)

# this is what your data probably looks like (1D arrays):
x,y,z = (a.flatten() for a in (x1,y1,z1))
# preferrably you would have it in the 2D array format
# but if the 1D is what you must work with:
# x is: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
#              0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
#              0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
# y is: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#              2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
#              4, 4, 4, 4, 4])

for i in range(0,25,5):
    # iterate over layers
    # (groups of same y)
    xs = x[i:i+5] # slice each layer
    ys = y[i:i+5]
    zs = z[i:i+5]
    layer = ys[0] # since in this case they are all equal.
    cs = numpy.random.random(3) # let's pick a random color for each layer
    ax.bar(xs, zs, zs=layer, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

plt.show()
```

Comment: what do you mean call it once for each plane? Can you show an example? I'm still unable to get it to work

Comment: Thank you. And how can I set the ticklabels on each axis in 3D space? thanks

Comment: In your code, you are not passing ys to "bar" -- is that intentional?

Comment: It is passed as `layer` (I thought this name would clarify the concept of planes -- i should probably have named it `plane`).  All y's are the same for each layer/plane.  I select the first value using `ys[0]`.  You need only pass one value of y if you want them all on the same plane.  `zs` and `zdir` are unfortunately named in my opinion as they often (and in this case) are along another axis other than z.

Comment: I get the error "3d" projection not valid. Also, do you know how to change the ticklabels?

Comment: @user248237:  Either go back to using `ax = Axes3D(fig)` or upgrade to matplotlib 1.0.  Try searching SO for "matplotlib ticklabels"